# Python-image-library (Pillow) issue with macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, conda

I have recently performed a `conda update --all`, when importing some standard libraries I have come across the following issue

```
import collections
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

which raised the following error

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
   import matplotlib.colorbar
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 44, in <module>
  import matplotlib.contour as contour
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 17, in <module>
  import matplotlib.text as text
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 16, in <module>
  from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
  from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 27, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 94, in <module>
  from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-37m- 
darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libwebp.7.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

I have installed on my machine `Catalina 10.15.6` and the `python` version of the `Conda 4.9.0 base` environment is `3.7.7`. The full list of packages can be found [here](https://github.com/Confareneoclassico/Environment/blob/main/packages_list).

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the environment? Have you tried creating a new environment?

Comment: @AMC, thanks for your feedback. Sure, the list of packages is available from here: https://github.com/Confareneoclassico/Environment/blob/main/packages_list cheers!

Comment: Which are the top-level dependencies? Does creating a new environment work?

Comment: Installed a new environment and this sorted it out, cheers!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. You really shouldn't use the base environment for development, it can easily lead to problems.

Comment: OK, I'll keep that in mind. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out upon @AMC's suggestion by installing a new environment via

`conda create --name base2` (where 'base2' is the name of the environment one wants to create and

`conda install -c xxx` (where xxx are the packages required).

A more effective way would be through a `.yml` environment file that would assure one has all the packages needed, although it could be prone to replicate the issue at the basis of this post.